# How to generate a ps file duplex attribute to only come up one time

Tags: xsl-fo, apache-fop

The ps file output from this xsl:fo using apache fop rendering generates a duplex attribute per page outputed. So if its 3 pages, the duplex attribute shows up in the ps file 3 times. Is there anyway in xsl:fo to force the attribute to only show up once in a generated output? by default the attribute shows up to be false for ps files also for each page.

PS File output: 
Per page this comes out

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:ps="http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/postscript">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
            <fo:layout-master-set>
                <fo:simple-page-master master-name="all" page-height="29.7cm" page-width="21cm" margin-top="1cm" margin-bottom="0.3cm" margin-left="1cm" margin-right="1cm">
                    <fo:region-body margin-top="0cm" margin-right="0cm" margin-bottom="1cm" margin-left="0cm" />
                    <fo:region-after extent="0.5cm" />
                </fo:simple-page-master>
                <fo:declarations>
                    <ps:ps-setpagedevice><![CDATA[<</Duplex true>>]]></ps:ps-setpagedevice>
                </fo:declarations>
            </fo:layout-master-set>
            <fo:page-sequence master-reference="all">
                <fo:static-content flow-name="xsl-region-after">
                    <fo:block font-family="Helvetica" font-size="6pt" color="#009999" margin-left="0cm" margin-right="0cm">
                </fo:block>
                </fo:static-content>
                <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
                    <fo:block>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="//region[@name='Main Region']" />
                    </fo:block>
                </fo:flow>
            </fo:page-sequence>
        </fo:root>
        <!--tEST-->
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="fo:*">
        <xsl:copy-of select="." />
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="th_region">
        <fo:block font-size="8pt" color="red">
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </fo:block>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="th_p">
        <fo:block>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </fo:block>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Expected results:
Only have the following attribute come out 1 time per file.

```
<<
/ImagingBBox null
/PageSize [595 842]
/Duplex true
>> setpagedevice
```

Comment: I believe that was and still is a bug in FOP. You should report it. See http://apache-fop.1065347.n5.nabble.com/Setting-duplex-for-postscript-output-td2491.html

Comment: thanks. I guess a programming solution to strip them out will be needed.